# How do I make alerts persistent with alert-user-configuration?

Tags: config

I'm using the [alert](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert) package, and I want alerts with the title "Agenda" to be persistent. It seems to me I should be able to do this:

```
(add-to-list 'alert-user-configuration
             '(((:title . "Agenda"))
               libnotify
               ((:persistent . t))))
```

but that doesn't work (alerts titled "Agenda" remain not persistent). I did this instead:

```
(alert-define-style 'who/alert-style-reminder
                    :title "Agenda reminders"
                    :notifier (lambda (info)
                                (alert-libnotify-notify (plist-put info :persistent t))))

(add-to-list 'alert-user-configuration
             '(((:title . "Agenda"))
               who/alert-style-reminder))
```

which does the job (alerts titled "Agenda" are indeed persistent), but I can't understand why my first attempt didn't work. Am I missing something about `alert-user-configuration`? What's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: apologies for the meaningless `config` tag. the only one I can really think of is `alert`, which I don't have enough rep to create.

Comment: More useful would be to explain what (and indeed where) the non-standard `alert-user-configuration` and `alert-define-style` are.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure why I thought `alert` was built in. Thanks, edited.